# setInterval() how to off and on when switching window

Tags: javascript

`setInterval()` how to off when switching to a different page and on then returns?

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('#myClass').load("new.php");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: call clearInterval? use a boolean?

Comment: I do not know how to write a function clearInterval when to jump to another page was turned off, and if passed this included

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "*jump to another page*".

Comment: What does "*and on then returns*" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var interval = setInterval(function() {$('#divClass').load("new.php");}, 5000);
     $(window).on('blur', function(){ clearInterval(interval) });

     $(window).on('focus', function(){ interval = setInterval(function() {
         $('#divClass').load("new.php");}, 5000)
     });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use clearInterval:

```
var ival = setInterval(function () {
               $('#myClass').load("new.php");
           }, 5000);


...

clearInterval(ival);
```

However, depending on what you mean by "jump to another page" you may not need to do anything.